# Symfony Security logout not clearing RememberMe token

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

Using Symfony 4 with a `security.yaml` like this:

```
encoders:
  App\Entity\User: sha256
providers:
    public_users:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/

        anonymous: ~

        form_login:
          login_path: login
          remember_me:    true

        remember_me:
            secret: "%kernel.secret%"
            name:  relevea_remember_me
            lifetime: 864000
            always_remember_me: false
            remember_me_parameter: user_login[stayConnected]

        logout:
            path: logout
            target: /about
            invalidate_session: false

access_control:
  - { path: ^/auth, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

`logout`operation is not clearing the rememberMe token.

I can see that `LogoutListener` (https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Http/Firewall/LogoutListener.php) is called after `RememberMeListener` (https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Http/Firewall/RememberMeListener.php) so for LogoutListener, the token is null and nothing is cleared :/

The listeners list from `TraceableFirewallListener`:

> Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ChannelListener
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\LogoutListener
>
> Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\RememberMeListener
>
> Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AnonymousAuthenticationListener
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AccessListener

Why the logout listener is before others?

Answer (score 0):

It looks a known issue since ... 2013!

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7104

So basically, you cant logout from a RememberMe token :/

Comment: You can try to create custom controller and call logout method manually. https://gist.github.com/sergeyfedotov/79e7cdf8ce4a960e5be1147417676ffb

Answer (score 0):

You can override the firewall listener to call logout listener the last as below

```
security.firewall:
    class: AppBundle\Security\FirewallListener
    arguments:
       - '@security.firewall.map'
       - '@event_dispatcher'
       - '@security.logout_url_generator'
    tags:
       - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }


use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security\FirewallMap;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FinishRequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\LogoutListener;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\FirewallMapInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutUrlGenerator;

class FirewallListener extends Firewall
{
    private $map;
    private $exceptionListeners;
    private $logoutUrlGenerator;
    private $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(FirewallMapInterface $map, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher, LogoutUrlGenerator $logoutUrlGenerator)
    {
        $this->map = $map;
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
        $this->exceptionListeners = new \SplObjectStorage();
        $this->logoutUrlGenerator = $logoutUrlGenerator;

        parent::__construct($map, $dispatcher);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->map instanceof FirewallMap && $config = $this->map->getFirewallConfig($event->getRequest())) {
            $this->logoutUrlGenerator->setCurrentFirewall($config->getName(), $config->getContext());
        }

        // register listeners for this firewall
        list($listeners, $exceptionListener) = $this->map->getListeners($event->getRequest());
        if (null !== $exceptionListener) {
            $this->exceptionListeners[$event->getRequest()] = $exceptionListener;
            $exceptionListener->register($this->dispatcher);
        }

        // initiate the listener chain
        $logoutListener = null;
        foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
            if ($listener instanceof LogoutListener) {
                $logoutListener = $listener;
                continue;
            }

            $listener->handle($event);

            if ($event->hasResponse()) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($logoutListener) {
            $logoutListener->handle($event);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onKernelFinishRequest(FinishRequestEvent $event)
    {
        if ($event->isMasterRequest()) {
            $this->logoutUrlGenerator->setCurrentFirewall(null);
        }

        parent::onKernelFinishRequest($event);
    }
}
```